# Unable to send attachment - Salesforce Docusign API

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I am trying to send attachment (record has one attachment) in opportunity record via Apex and Docusign "CreateAndSendEnvelope" API.

But I am getting this error "*The DocuSign EnvelopeId:Exception - System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: An Error Occurred during anchor tag processing. Invalid document faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx*"

Below is the piece of code used.

```
 // Render the contract
        System.debug('Rendering the contract');
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/RenderContract');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',contract.Id);

        //Blob pdfBlob = pageRef.getContent();     
        Attachment att = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE Parentid = :contract.Id LIMIT 1];
        Blob pdfBlob = att.Body; 


        // Document
        DocuSignAPI.Document document = new DocuSignAPI.Document();
        document.ID = 1;
        document.pdfBytes = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
        document.Name = 'Contract';
        document.FileExtension = 'pdf';
        envelope.Documents = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfDocument();
        envelope.Documents.Document = new DocuSignAPI.Document[1];
        envelope.Documents.Document[0] = document;

        // Recipient
        System.debug('getting the contact');
        Contact contact = [SELECT email, FirstName, LastName 
            from Contact where id = :contract.CustomerSignedId];

        DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
        recipient.ID = 1;
        recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
        recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
        recipient.Email = contact.Email;
        recipient.UserName = contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName;

        // This setting seems required or you see the error:
        // "The string '' is not a valid Boolean value. 
        // at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToBoolean(String s)" 
        recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;      

        envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient();
        envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[1];
        envelope.Recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;

        // Tab
        DocuSignAPI.Tab tab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
        tab1.Type_x = 'SignHere';
        tab1.RecipientID = 1;
        tab1.DocumentID = 1;
        tab1.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
        tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'By:';


        DocuSignAPI.Tab tab2 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
        tab2.Type_x = 'DateSigned';
        tab2.RecipientID = 1;
        tab2.DocumentID = 1;
        tab2.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
        tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'Date Signed:';

        envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
        envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[2];
        envelope.Tabs.Tab[0] = tab1;        
        envelope.Tabs.Tab[1] = tab2;        

        System.debug('Calling the API');
        try {
            DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es 
            = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
            envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;
        } catch ( CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
            envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
        }
```

Any ideas how to overcome this error?

Thanks.

Comment: What server is your docusign account on (it looks like demo, but just double checking)? when did you start seeing this error?

Comment: it is demo server ..i saw this error one hour back.. initially  i was trying the code in this link : [link](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures).And it worked fine on rendering the whole record to pdf...but now i tried sending attachments only instead of whole record.. i started to get this error..Any inputs pls..tnx

Answer (score 0):

The Original Poster's (OP's) comment is

> it worked fine on rendering the whole record to pdf...but now i tried sending attachments only instead of whole record.. i started to get this error.

So my guess is that the envelope request has a document problem.

Best way to debug: see what is being sent to the DocuSign platform.

Try the [beta API logger](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-signature-api-logging-made-easy/) or the [regular logger](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging). Then add the log to your question by *editing* your question.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded log file and can see 9 files created with names, 00_ok_Getusersignature, 01_notfound_getuserprofileimage, 02_OK_getaccountsettings, 03_Ok_Getusersettings, 04_OK_getusersignatures, 05_Ok_Getuserprofile, 06_Ok_ExecuteloggedApiBusinessLogic, 07_Internal server error_Createandsendenvelope, 08_Ok_Updateaccountsettigns. Kindly let me know if log information required for any of these files to check on this further. Thanks

Comment: I resolved it by myself.. document.FileExtension = 'pdf';..actually i am passing word document, so i changed document.FileExtension = 'pdf' to 'docx'. it is working fine..Thanks,...

Answer (score 0):

This problem came across me with same error . 
" An Error Occurred during anchor tag processing. Invalid document faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx "

you need to replace anchor tab string with desired string given in your attached document where signature is required.

Replace :

tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'By:';
 tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'Date Signed:';

To :

tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'Signature label in your document'; 
 tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'Signature label in your document';